# How can I calculate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate the partial sum for an equation. How can I calculate the sum for 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}\ \text{?}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Partial sum to infinity ???

Comment: A handful of older questions which are in a similar spirit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/how-to-prove-sum-frac14n2-1-frac12-frac12-times-2n1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265277/sum-of-this-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac14n2-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571293/sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac13-8n-16n2?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306992/calculate-this-sum-sum-frac14n14n3
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993890/how-to-find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-k-2-infty-frac1k2-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with partial fraction decomposition by finding the roots of the denominator\begin{align}\frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}&=\frac{1}{\left(4n-3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}=\frac14\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)\end{align} In this way, the initial series can be written as telescoping series and therefore you can calculate the partial sum up to $N \in \mathbb N$ and then let $N\to+\infty$ as follows:
\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N}&\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)=\\[0.2cm]&=\left(1-\frac15\right)+\left(\frac15-\frac19\right)+\left(\frac19-\frac1{15}\right)\dots+\left(\frac{1}{4N-3}-\frac1{4N+1}\right)\\[0.2cm]&=1+\left(\frac15-\frac15\right)+\left(\frac19-\frac19\right)+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{4N-3}-\frac1{4N-3}\right)-\frac1{N+1}\\[0.2cm]&=1-\frac{1}{4N+1}
\end{align}
So, returning to initial series
\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac14\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac14\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)\\[0.2cm]&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac1{4N+1}\right)=\frac14(1-0)=\frac14\end{align}

Comment: Is this series not actually undefined because of $n=3$ giving us a undefined term in the sequence?

Comment: @K.Power Yes, right I have a mistake.

Comment: The factorization is wrong, this answer shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: The factorization should give $(4n-3)(4n+1)$

Comment: @K.Power Yes, thank you .

Comment: @YvesDaoust Comments like the ones from K.Power are more helpful.

Comment: That was intended to @carmenmitru.

Answer (score 4):

Notice, use partial fractions: $\frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)$ as follows  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{13}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac{1}{4n-7}-\frac{1}{4n-3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-0\right)=\color{red}{\frac 14}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT.

This is a telescoping sum:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{16n^2-8n-3}={1\over4}\sum_{n=1}^{k}(a_n-a_{n+1})={1\over4}(a_1-a_{k+1}),
$$
where $a_n=1/(4n-3)$.

Comment: The answer is wonderful.